# How to get current padding of a widget?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qwidget

I know how to tweak the padding property of a widget:

```
widget.setStyleSheet("padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px");
```

or

```
widget.setStyleSheet("padding: 5px");
```

Which does same padding all sides.

But how do I get current padding? I don't see a way to `qDebug() << padding`.

If the use case matters, I have a vertical layout with three combo boxes, already set layout content margins to zero and space around the component vanishes. But there is still some vertical space between the combo boxes.

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
QVBoxLayout *vLayout = new QVBoxLayout(widget);
vLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

vLayout->addWidget(new QComboBox);
vLayout->addWidget(new QComboBox);
vLayout->addWidget(new QComboBox);

QToolBar *toolbar = new QToolBar;
toolbar->addWidget(widget);
addToolBar(toolbar);
```

[image]

And by settting vertical space in the layout I get:

[image]

Reference: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox

Comment: Do you need it specifically for combo-box? There the padding applies to the items when "expanded" (if i remember correctly).

Comment: For some widgets _contentsMargins_ returns what you want, but if the widget has more margins on top of the padding (from the children/layout/frame) this doesn't return what you want.

Comment: Question updated with some description of use case.

Comment: Did you mean to say (in your addition) that the issue is when you hide the combos? It's not clear what you mean. If you're trying to hide the widgets and remove the layout spacing between them, you'll need to get more clever (it's a PITA) or just remove the widget(s) from the layout, hide them, and re-insert into layout to show them again. You could also possibly use QSS rules to target the visible state of a widget: `QComboBox { padding: 5px; } QComboBox:hidden { padding: 0; }`

Comment: Question updated with some code and image.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: That helps a lot, is it possible to get even closer?

Comment: Maybe, but you'll need to figure out where that extra space is coming from. It is from `QMacStyle` somewhere. See screenshot I added to my answer on how it looks with the `Fusion` style set and a dark palette -- you can see how tight the spacing is. Setting CSS on the QComboBox is probably the only way to get rid of the extra space, if possible at all. Or is that a desktop preference on Mac somewhere?

Comment: Yeah the frame margins/padding is inside `QMacStyle` and at least somewhat controlled by desktop settings. https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/styles/mac/qmacstyle_mac.mm.html#5421   You could try setting some box model CSS properties (eg. a border style or padding/margins) on the combo boxes to override the QMacStyling, but then you'll probably need to style the rest of the control to try and match the default theme, which of course could be light or dark.

Answer (score 1):

Setting a style sheet doesn't change the actual margins in any way that you can query. The active `QStyle` has control over the final look of the widget, which in this case is `QStylesheetStyle` and it sets the margins/etc when painting the item. The parsed CSS isn't available anywhere else except the `QStylesheetStyle` internals.

*ADDED* based on follow-up comment:

There is no official way to access `QStylesheetStyle`, it is completely private within Qt.  But even if you really wanted to use the `widgets-private` parts, the info is still buried deep inside the `QStylesheetStyle` private data... I'm not sure you could get to it even if you loaded `qstylesheetstyle_p.h` because a lot of the data (and methods to extract parts of it) is just in the CPP file itself.

If you really want to dig through it... https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qstylesheetstyle.cpp.html  (you can see right away there are definitions in the CPP which are required for handling the CSS and doing any lookups, like the `PseudoElement` enum at the top)

*ADDED* in response to edited question:

It's the default `QVBoxLayout` spacing adding extra padding. Add:

`vLayout->setSpacing(0);`  (or whatever padding you want between items)

[image]

Comment: What about querrying `QStylesheetStyle` then?

Comment: @KcFnMi I added a further explanation to my answer. TL;DR: Not possible.